# Irregular adhesion on Creality glass bed

Tags: adhesion, temperature

I have an Ender 5 pro and upgraded from the magnetic bed to the glass version. I print with Prusament PLA on 65 °C bed temp and 220 °C extruder temp. I measured that the glass surface has ~58 °C in the center and ~56 °C on the corners. That should be in the specs of the spool which has a printed recommendation of 50 +- 10 °C for bed and 215 +- 10 °C for extruder temps.

Now I also have a BLTouch and use the TH3D firmware so Z offsets should work correctly and are done with the Z offset wizard present (nozzle touching the bed).

The problem I currently have is that the first layers have "lifts" in them. Also, it seems that the layer itself is not 0.2 mm everywhere. It's close to 0.23 mm on the edges but on the inner there are variances up to 0.36 mm.

Currently, I slice with Cura 4.8.0 on Standard Quality 0.2 mm

How do I get rid of the lifts and irregularity in the layer? Is it a problem with the bed?

[image: Lifts]

[image: darker areas are 0.36mm]

Comment: Are you using anything else to help the print adhere to the bed like blue tape, glue stick, etc.?

Comment: No, only the pre applied structure ( https://www.amazon.de/Creality-Glasplatte-Verbesserte-Drucker-Plattform/dp/B0836PMMZ5/ )

Comment: Is the surface that the glass bed sits on thoroughly clean? Also, it is usual to put the clips on the edges, maybe 3-4 cm in, not on the corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I've seen lifting, away from the edges of the part like this, is when the bed is contaminated with something which will stop the print sticking, like fingerprints and such.

A thorough wipe-down with IPA on the heated bed is usually enough to stop it.

Comment: I did wipe it two times with isoprop now and i got a print from it. Also i have seen that my bed (from the autolevel bltouch) is not flat (but i guess thats due to the frame not beeing level): https://drive.google.com/uc?id=10y4tr6eWzHM_oLES5mwY-sMNB66Q4M7K - So i have ~1mm difference over the whole bed

Comment: @geNAZt Have you got a straight edge, like a steel rule, that you could use to check the flatness of the glass when it is and isn't on the printer, at room temperature and heated up?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen lifts that aren't on the edge of the print, such as warping, or the entire printed surface lifts.  When I get something like in your photograph, it's because the print surface isn't flat and the first layer matches the surface topology.  If the second image shows the print surface, it looks like blobs on the surface that may be keeping it from being flat.

The first layer thickness greatly depends on how high the nozzle is above the print surface.  If this distance varies, the first layer thickness will vary.  Also make sure your print surface is free of any substances that the hot extruded material might cause to boil.

Any chance you are removing the print from the bed before it cools down.  This can distort the print if the material is still soft.

Comment: This is my printing surface: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RkxSiQkVyq8JlBp2BxNuzcTi7kkkcTtM/view?usp=sharing

I clean it with isoprop every ~4-5 prints and wait until it fully evaporated. Also i thought that the BLTouch should take care of variance in the print bed itself? According to the bed it should have a variance of 0.15mm in itself